# Unity animations sprite disappearing

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, animation

I was recently making a `Unity2D iOS Game` with `Unity 2D GameKit` and it uses `Animation` to make a robot look like he is walking but I noticed a delay after the animation which makes the **bot disappear for a frame**!
Is there any way to stop the sprite from disappearing?

Links:

[Video of disappearing robot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WBmhz0g9FqmytPmrhLNTdGgjeSsLA-PK/view?usp=sharing) - Google Drive

[Screenshot of Animation window with blank "8" Frame!](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vb8vyIpyfwLX2YG-9o3wbCmd8lze8ozp/view?usp=sharing) - Google Drive